# split a \xrightarrow into two lines

Tags: line-breaking, arrows, two-column

I'm using the command `\xrightarrow{}[]` in a two column document.
The problem is that the string  above the arrow is too long and the arrow  ends outside the column. Is there a way to "split" the arrow over two different lines?

Comment: You can't really split a single symbol like that. And I'm not sure it would be a good idea to do so anyway.

Comment: But you probably can split in two lines the text over the arrow

Comment: Thanks Seamus and JLDiaz for your answers! Do you know how to split in two lines the text over the arrow??? Because \xrightarrow{text1 \\ text2}[] is no effective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, to split the index below or above a `\sum`, or similar operator, use `\substack` from the `amsmath` package (or one of the other ams paclages, I'm not sure).

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\[
a \xrightarrow{\substack{x \to 0 \\ y \to 0}} b   
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bruno! I think this is a very helpful solution!